# How to neglect this error in windows application using crystal reports

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports

this is a formula  that i have used to select records based on string array 'aa '

crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "({Table3.logindate}  = '" + aa[i] + "')" 
for e.g aa[i]=aa[0],aa[1],aa[2]
it will select only the records of aa[2]
please give me a valuable solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string formula = string.Empty;
formula = "(";
for(int i = 0; i< aa.Length - 1; i++)
{
formula += "{Table3.logindate} = '" + aa[i] + "'" 
if(i != aa.length -1)
{
formula += " && " //I don't know && works for AND operator in SelectionFormula 
}
}
formula = ")";
crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = formula ;
```

And it is no to neglect error, it is to fix the error. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off to create a crystal parameter that allows multiple values (essentially an array). Then you simply set the parameter value in code...

```
rptDoc.SetParameterValue("param_name", aa);
```

then your crystal selection formula becomes...

```
{Table3.logindate} in {param_name}
```